Current measurement with c BJT current mirror
I was asked to make an analog current measurement circuit and I was asked to do it with BJT. For this, my supervisor told me to use the bjt current mirror topology (the one with 4 BJTs). I found a circuit like the one I show in the attachment, but what I really want is to measure current. I need to measure it to show 5V proportionally to 2A. 2A = 5V, 1A=2.5V. 0.5A=1.125V, I should take the current measurement current value proportionally as voltage and do this with a BJT current mirror. I don't fully understand the topology and what do I need to change and what do I need to play with? Can you help me?


What is the Vcc? A 5V? How much voltage drop can be “waisted” on shunt? If the requirement is less than 500mV it will lead to very rough measurement.

@MichalPodmanický Vcc is 5V. Actually I don't know all details because I am intern. Supervisor asked me to design a circuit where we could proportion 2A to 5V and observe it. He also asked me to do this with BJT current mirror.

Please add simulation results (after all, you are using LTspice for the schematic and you appear to have enacted a transient analysis over 10 ms).

By using 0.1 ohm shunt at 2A the drop across shunt is 0.2V.
Setting gain of T1 with Rc/Re ratio to 21 you are getting 4.2V Vcurr (at 2A).
You cannot set the circuit to output full 5V Vcurr since there is a room needed for some Vre and Vce of T1.
The 10k doesn’t play a role much but T2 “diode” drop can be adjusted a bit (like 0.6-0.65V) so you can fine tune the I_load vs. Vcurr.


The additional NPN current mirror, seems to make the output more linear, but it also makes the right-branch bottom resistor value actually meaningful. So that part of your answer would be specific to your circuit, but less so to the OP's circuit.

Just change some resistor's values ...
Note that the change of resistor of 50 Ohm is very "critical".
Simulated at two temperatures with microcap v12.
Gain is calculated with (my) R2/R1 (To be demonstrated).

If you change this value to 70 Ohms, here is what you get ...

With 10 Ohm, I get this waveform "saturated" @4.134 V.


I get around 4V every time and the maximum went up to 4.2. What should I do to get this closer to 5V. I changed your R1 to 10 ohm, I get max 4.2V. I think I cannot get absolutely around 5V right?

Yes . You can't get around 5V because the voltage of collector Q1 change also. See new picture.
